# How to fix CWE-20: Improper Input Validation

Tags: java, static-analysis, polaris

I have used polaris for static scan on one of my projects. The scan results shows that one of the java class has CWE-20 defect. It is reported for this particular line.

```
String propValue = req.getParameter(propertyName);
```

I have tried a few possible ways to resolve this but was not able to resolve. Is there any way that this can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

[CWE-20](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/20.html) is intended to protect against where the product receives input or data, but it does not validate or incorrectly validates that the input has the properties that are required to process the data safely and correctly.

Your single line of code doesn't really explain the nature of your problem... I'm assuming that you are simply using `propValue` without validation?

Thus the mitigation is to de-taint the input, to protect against dodgy data, before using that input.  So you need to do something like:

```
String propValue = req.getParameter(propertyName);
if ( propValue.validate() )
{
  ... use it
}
else
{
  ... error condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this to validate the input

```java
String propertyName = req.getParameter("propertyName");
if (propertyName == null || !Pattern.matches("[A-Za-z0-9_]+", propertyName)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid property name.");
}
String propValue = req.getParameter(propertyName);
```